# FxCop 10.0 can't find CA2000 "Dispose objects before losing scope"

Tags: c#, fxcop

I'm trying to run FXCop 10.0 stand-alone (not using Visual Studio Code Analysis) and I can't find the rule **CA2000 "Dispose objects before losing scope"**

I've added **ReliabilityRules.dll** but this only seems to have 4 or 5 rules unrelated to CA2000.

I've scoured the web and there are statements that this rule had been removed, but then ones that say it was re-added with 10.0.

Does anyone know the state of availability of this rule?

Comment: I don't have official information but can confirm that [this rule sometimes fires in error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/591703/ca2000-fires-incorrectly-when-using-block-contains-more-than-x-statements) - in VS2012, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was added back, but only in the paid version that ships as part of Visual Studio, not in the free FxCop distribution.  If you have an edition of VS 2010 that includes static analysis, this rule is in the DataflowRules.dll assembly (which requires use of the new dataflow rules engine).

Comment: bummer, we have a paid version but not one that includes static analysis.  We are going to use Gendarme instead: http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme